# Why some hair particules doesn't apply material?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, particles

I'm trying to create grass field.

I have created a group of grass. I have assigned the same material (blue for the test) to every object of this group (called *Herbe*).
[image]

Then I have created a plane, subdivided and applied fractal. Then I apply particles on it to get grass springing. This is the particules option I have chosen :

[image]

Despite this, all is not blue. Some groups of grass doesn't take the blue color.
Would you know the reason ??
[image]

Thanks !

Comment: Can you provide the .blend file?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Finally, it was because I had duplicated my plane, that's why I got this result....